# Filter Array - if the array exists in the array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

How Do I filter an array by checking if an array is listed in the array?

`cryptoData: Array(100) 0: {CoinInfo: {…}, RAW: {…}, DISPLAY: {…}}`

I am trying to check if cryptoData (Array) contains the DISPLAY array and if it does not contain DISPLAY - remove it from the cryptoData array and set the filterArray with only the elements that contain the DISPLAY Array.

My attempt:

```
var filterdArray = cryptoData.filter(function (el) {
  return cryptoData[el] === 'DISPLAY';
});

this.setState({
  cryptos: filterdArray,
  refreshing: false,
});
```

Comment: `el` is the element, not the array index. Why do you have `cryptoData[el]`?

Comment: Please be sure to format code correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the value is an object you can use `hasOwnProperty` to check if the object has a property.

```js
var filterdArray = cryptoData.filter(function (el) {
  return el.hasOwnProperty('DISPLAY');
});

this.setState({
  cryptos: filterdArray,
  refreshing: false,
});
```

Comment: what is the difference between the first parameter and second in the filter callback function?

Comment: the first one is the element and the second one is the index at which the element is located.